# comparator java <E>

Tags: java, class, generics, abstract, comparator

My question is the following,
I have an interface that requires me to return `java.util.Comparator <E>`, my question is, how can i implement an abstract class that somehow returns a generic Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `Comparator<?>` and suppress the warnings.

Keep in mind that generics exist only at compile-time, except for reflection. By the time it's runtime, the JVM is operating on the raw classes. So, at runtime, all `Comparators` are the same type. So if you turn off the warnings and return a `Comparator` that just compares `Object` instances, it will work just as it would have in Java 1.2.

Comment: I doubt this is a good idea except when one knows what is going on - which is obviously not the case with Mares.

Answer (score 1):

What type is the class?  If you had this one way to do it non-abstractly:

For this:

```
class Name {
  String name;   
}
```

You could do this as a one off:

```
Comparator<Name> nameComparator = new Comparator<Name>() {
  public int compare(Name o1, Name o2) {
     return o1.name.compare(o2.name);
  } 

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
     return super.equals(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the equals method here? What if you call nameComparator.equals(nameComparator)?

Comment: Typo.  Was subconsciously writing a Stackoverflow :)

Comment: This one is not buggy anymore, but it still doesn't serve any purpose, since it override the default implementation with... the default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a valid reason for the interface to require you to return a Comparator<E> . You could return a Comparator with no type parameter (which is then in fact *non-generic*), but there is a chance that it will break somewhere.

What you could do:

Implement a generic class (=which takes a type parameter itself) and returns a generic Comparator.

```
public MyImpl<E> implements SomeInterface {

...
   public Comparator<E> createComparator() {
      ...
   }

}
```

Ignoring (suppressing) warnings, although it could work in your situation, will only give trouble in the long run and probably isn't the best way to go.